# MYSQL 30 days query

Tags: mysql

i have this kind of query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM `reportinc` 
WHERE `Data/ora apertura` >=  '21/01/13 00:00:00' 
    AND `Data/ora apertura` <= '21/01/13 18:00:00'
```

I have to repeat this query for 30 days past from today.
How automate it?

Instead of daytime: 21/01/13 i have to insert something like TODAY -1, TODAY -2 etc etc but my own specified timestamp.

How to?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: `Data/ora apertura` is this a field name? :O

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WHERE `Data/ora apertura` >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
  AND `Data/ora apertura` <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                                          + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR_SECOND
```

Comment: Is not working....my query 
  
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `reportinc` WHERE `Data/ora apertura` >=  '21/01/13 00:00:00' AND `Data/ora apertura` <= '21/01/13 18:00:00'
  
Results is 176
  
If i try 
  
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `reportinc` WHERE `Data/ora apertura` >=  'CURRENT_DATE 00:00:00' AND `Data/ora apertura` <= 'CURRENT_DATE 18:00:00'
  
or
  
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `reportinc` WHERE `Data/ora apertura` >=  'CURRENT_DATE' AND `Data/ora apertura` <= 'CURRENT_DATE'
  
results is 0

Comment: @svratonzo: You're placing `CURRENT_DATE` inside a string literal, which is not what I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT    TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(your_table_column_name) <= 30;
```

Or use DATEDIFF

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('1997-12-31 23:59:59','1997-12-30');
        -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM `reportinc`
WHERE `Data/ora apertura` 
BETWEEN 
    CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
AND 
    CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY + '18:00:00'
```